# Jenkins Pipeline: Catch Abort from UI and Handle it safely for dockerized agent

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, terraform

I am running a job defined with Jenkins declarative pipeline.

The pipeline uses a docker agent as the worker which is used to run terraform (plan and apply)

When a user clicks "abort" or "cancel" in the Jenkins UI, the pipeline is terminated (SIGTERM) is sent to the Docker process (I think ...).

This results in terraform being shut down uncleanly.

What I would like to do is the following:

- If a user clicks abort in the Jenkins UI, catch this before any process is actually terminated
- and instead, shut down the pipeline another way (maybe freeze the agent or something safer like send a cancel to the running process in the docker container).

I have tried the following:

- `try{}catch(err){}`, however this aborts the pipeline, terminating the docker agent before actually executing the actions in the `catch`. So not much use.
- a post{} action for the stage, which also just carries out a post action in the event of an ABORT but after the abort.

Question:

Is there a method in Jenkins (preferably using Jenkins declarative pipeline) to handle the ABORT signal *before* it is actually applied and decide whether to abort or not ?

(Value: If this is possible it would enable me to smoothly manage the abort of Terraform jobs by users, avoiding infrastructure damage.)

Many thanks in advance for any help!